# Gerar todas combinações dada uma lista em python

Tags: python

Já procurei bastante e não encontrei em nenhum lugar o que quero exatamente. O que eu quero é, dada uma lista de caracteres, gerar todas as combinações possíveis de tamanho x até tamanho y.
Exemplo:
dado 0,1,2 e pedir combinações de tamanho de 1 a 2
gerar:
(00)
(11)
(22)
(01)
(10)
(02)
(20)
(12)
(21)

Queria gerar, por exemplo, todas as combinações de 8 a 20 caracteres dada uma lista de 70 caracteres (sei que seria extremamente grande).

O código que eu fiz:

```
from itertools import permutations

caracteres = [0, 1, 2]
for subset in permutations(caracteres, 2):
    print(subset)
```

gera apenas:
(01)
(02)
(10)
(12)
(20)
(21)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para gerares todas as combinações de 8 chars de uma lista de 70 elementos vai ser extremamente custoso, 70<sup>8</sup> (576,480,100,000,000) combinações... Boa sorte :P

Para gerar todas as combinações possíveis, incluindo caracteres repetidos, usa `product`:

```
from itertools import product

caracteres = [0, 1, 2]
permsList = []
genComb = product(caracteres, repeat=2) # aqui e onde tens de especificar o numero de chars que cada combinacao tenha
for subset in genComb:
    print(subset) # tuple retornado com uma combinacao por loop
    permsList.append(subset)
print(permsList) # [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

Nem precisas do ciclo for (a não ser que precises de fazer mais alguma operação no loop) basta transformares o *[generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)* retornado numa lista/set/tuple para armazenares os resultados, sendo só preciso isto:

```
from itertools import product

caracteres = [0, 1, 2]
permsList = list(product(caracteres, repeat=2))
print(permsList) # [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

Podes também remover os tuples e ficares com uma lista de strings, para isso, visto que temos inteiros e não strings temos de os tranformar em string:

```
from itertools import product

caracteres = [0, 1, 2]
permsList = [''.join(str(i) for i in x) for x in product(caracteres, repeat=2)]
print(permsList) # ['00', '01', '02', '10', '11', '12', '20', '21', '22']
```

Se tiveres strings em vez de inteiros nos tuples podes só:

```
permsList = [''.join(x) for x in product(caracteres, repeat=2)]
```

Comment: obrigado Miguel

Comment: de nada @JúlioCésar, ainda bem que resolveu